# Handling authentication state in Flutter with navigation

Tags: ios, dart, google-signin, flutter

I'm using Google Sign In to handle user authentication in a Flutter app. This works great for a single-view app (no routing), but as soon as I try to add some routes and manage the routes effectively things get pretty tricky.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but what I think I want is a stateful widget at the top level which controls my signed in variable and auth methods. This top level stateful widget also controls my routing. Here are some snippets from my current setup:

```
class SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  GoogleSignInAccount _currentUser;
  ...

  Future<Null> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _handleSignOut() async {
    _googleSignIn.disconnect();
  } 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: _pageTitle,
      home: new Home(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        "/": (BuildContext context) => new Home(),
        "/settings": (BuildContext context) => new Settings(),
        "/login": (BuildContext context) => new Login()
      },
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

My assumption here is that my state would get passed down into the nested widgets but I'm not seeing the `_currentUser` variable inside `Home()` for instance.

In other frameworks you can specify methods to run on route load, it'd be nice if there was an elegant way to check if _currentUser existed before loading a route so that I could push a new route if a user wasn't logged in.

If anyone has experience with combining routing and authentication in Flutter apps I'd really appreciate a step in the right direction. Most tutorials I've found are for one or the other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make your `SignIn` widget an [`InheritedWidget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html), and add some property to it containing your user state (lets say `userState`), you can add a method like this to it:

```
static UserState of(BuildContext context, { bool nullOk: false }) {
    assert(context != null);
    assert(nullOk != null);
    final SignIn signInWidget = context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(SignIn);
    if (signInWidget != null)
      return signInWidget.userState;
    if (nullOk)
      return null;
    throw new FlutterError(
      'Attempted to find UserState without a SignInWidget parent.\n'
      'The context used was:\n'
      '  $context'
    );
}
```

And then you can call

```
SignIn.of(context)
```

In your routes to get the `UserState`.

There are other ways to do this - putting your data in a redux store for example, or creating chains of callbacks (e.g. exposing a callback on your `SignInWidget` that gets passed along to child routes).  This is probably the cleanest built-in way of doing it, especially if you plan to just have this widget live at the top of your tree anyway - but if you adopted some other state management strategy (like using redux), you'd probably want to consider using that.

Comment: How do you go about learning more advanced stuff beyond the basic stuff? Are these techniques explained at flutter.io ?

Comment: It's all documented there, although some of it is matters of knowing where to look.  Take a look at their examples and tutorials though, the documentation and examples are improving regularly.

Answer (score 4):

How about adding:

```
static Widget checkAuth(Widget page) {
    if (currentUser == null) {
        return Login();
    } else {
        return page;
    }
}
...

  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
    "/": (BuildContext context) => checkAuth(Home()),
    "/settings": (BuildContext context) => checkAuth(Settings()),
    "/login": (BuildContext context) => new Login()
  },
...
```